# swift range greater than lower bound

Tags: swift, swift3, nsrange

I need to implement experience filter like this

- 0 to 2 years
- 2+ to 4 years

How to express it in swift range?

Problem is I can't express more than 2 to 4 years. While I can do less than upper bounds. e.g. like this

```
let underTen = 0.0..<10.0
```

I need something like this (greater than lower bound)

```
let uptoTwo = 0.0...2.0
let twoPlus = 2.0>..4.0  // compiler error
```

---

Currently I am doing

```
let twoPlus = 2.1...4.0
```

But this is not perfect.

Comment: Are you working with Ints?

Comment: @Alexander edit: No. experience could be fraction in years

Comment: Do you use arrays? You can try to use `filter` for sorting

Comment: is (2+1)..4 work for you?

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov plz explain

Comment: As I undestand, you need to use [0, 2) and (2, 4] ranges, so 2 years experience doesn't include any range, right?

Comment: @WarifAkhandRishi Your question and your example contradict each other. Your question asks to segment make ranges for "0 to 2" (2 is included) and "2+ to 4), but your example shows "0 up to, not including 2" and "2+ to 4

Comment: @Horst no it could be fraction in years

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov I need to use [0,2] and [2+,4] ranges. 2 years experience included in first range (0,2) not in 2nd range (2+,4)

Comment: How do you use the two ranges? If you use `0.0...2.0` and `2.0...4.0` then it will work as desired if you check the first range and then the second range. If the value is 2.0 it will be caught by the first range. This means only values over 2.0 will be caught by the second range.

Comment: @rmaddy :) like it. didn't come to my mind. but sill it depends on my checking sequence. Is there any better solution to this?

Comment: You need to use a switch

Comment: Warif: rather than adding 0.1, add `Double.ulp` it's as close to 2.0 as you can possibly go, without being at 2.0

Comment: `switch years { case 0...2: print(true) case 2...4: print(true) }`

Comment: It will print true only at the first case if years is equal to 2.0

Comment: @Alexander liked the idea but `Double.ulp` shows compiler error.

Comment: @Warif look up the documentation, it was something like that, I don't remember and I can't check right now

Comment: Just add `2.0.ulp`

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### `nextUp` from the `FloatingPoint` protocol

You can make use of the [`nextUp`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpoint/1848104-nextup) property of `Double`, as blueprinted in the [`FloatingPoint` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpoint) to which `Double` conforms

> **nextUp**
>
> The least representable value that compares greater than this value.
>
> For any finite value `x`, `x.nextUp` is greater than `x`. ...

I.e.:

```
let uptoTwo = 0.0...2.0
let twoPlus = 2.0.nextUp...4.0
```

The property [`ulp`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpoint/1847492-ulp), also blueprinted in the `FloatingPoint` protocol, has been mentioned in the comments to your question. For most numbers, this is the difference between `self` and the next greater representable number:

> **ulp**
>
> The unit in the last place of self.
>
> This is the unit of the least significant digit in the significand of
>   `self`. For most numbers `x`, this is the difference between `x` and
>   the next greater (in magnitude) representable number. ...

`nextUp` does, in essence, return the value of `self` with the addition of `ulp`. So for your example above, the following is equivalent (whereas, imo, `nextup` should be preferred in this use case).

```
let uptoTwo = 0.0...2.0 
let twoPlus = (2.0+2.0.ulp)...4.0
```

---

You might also want to consider replacing the lower bound literal in `twoPlus` with the `upperBound` property of the preceding `uptoTwo` range:

```
let uptoTwo = 0.0...2.0                       // [0, 2] closed-closed
let twoPlus = uptoTwo.upperBound.nextUp...4.0 // (2, 4] open-closed

if uptoTwo.overlaps(twoPlus) {
    print("the two ranges overlap ...")
}
else {
    print("ranges are non-overlapping, ok!")
}
// ranges are non-overlapping, ok!
```

Comment: @sketchyTech I appreciate the edit, but there a (semantic) issue with defining a new custom operator such as this one. In Swift 3, the `Range` type is explicitly described as one defining a half-open interval (using e.g. the half-open operator `..<`) from a lower bound and _not including, an upper bound_. On the other hand, the `ClosedRange` is descried as a closed interval including its lower as well as its upper bound. Your operator above construct a `ClosedRange` instance, but may be confusing as it _does not include_ the lower bound given when constructing the _closed_ interval, ...

Comment: ... contrary to what we might expect when instantiation an instance of the `ClosedRange` type. If we were to really add a new half-open operator (excluding the lower bound), we should, for semantics, also create a new Range type, covering this special half-open case (which we don't really like to do, though). Consequently, I will revert your edit (this time; still much appreciated, many/most of my answers can always be improved!), but feel free to add your own answer using the custom operator.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than create a new type of range you can instead create a method that will identify values above the lower bound:

```
extension ClosedRange {
    func containsAboveLowerBound(value:Bound) -> Bool {
        if value > self.lowerBound {
            return self.contains(value)
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

implementing it like so:

```
let r = 2.0...3.0
r.containsAboveLowerBound(value: 2.0) // false
r.containsAboveLowerBound(value: 2.01) // true
```

Comment: valid answer +1. looking for simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

If your actual purpose is to use *ranges* for filtering, how about making them as closures?

```
let underTen = {0.0 <= $0 && $0 < 10.0}
let upToTwo = {0.0 <= $0 && $0 <= 2.0}
let twoPlus = {2.0 <  $0 && $0 <= 4.0}
```

You can use such *filtering closures* like this:

```
class Client: CustomStringConvertible {
    var experience: Double
    init(experience: Double) {self.experience = experience}
    var description: String {return "Client(\(experience))"}
}
let clients = [Client(experience: 1.0),Client(experience: 2.0),Client(experience: 3.0)]
let filteredUnderTen = clients.filter {underTen($0.experience)}
print(filteredUnderTen) //->[Client(1.0), Client(2.0), Client(3.0)]
let filteredUpToTwo = clients.filter {upToTwo($0.experience)}
print(filteredUpToTwo) //->[Client(1.0), Client(2.0)]
let filteredTwoPlus = clients.filter {twoPlus($0.experience)}
print(filteredTwoPlus) //->[Client(3.0)]
```

Comment: Im not using it for this problem. But i'll use it in future for other type of situations. Showed me something new thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does it,

```
extension ClosedRange where Bound == Int {
    func containsExclusiveOfBounds(_ bound: Bound) -> Bool {
        return !(bound == lowerBound || bound == upperBound)
    }
}
```